# Does python's `os.system` ever throw an exception?

Tags: python, command-line, exception, operating-system

Might the esteemed `os.system` of Python fame throw an exception? If so, which ones?

Comment: `os.system()` is *hardly* esteemed anymore...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: yes:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system(None)
TypeError ...
```

Long answer: look here http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements to see how to avoid using `os.system`.

Comment: I realize that's just one example. I'm not aware of any other possible exception types; 'wrong' string or unicode parameters are all just passed to the shell. Still... it's better to avoid using os.system.

Answer (score 5):

On POSIX systems it appears to be a straight pass-through to `system()` (listing from Python 2.7.1's posixmodule.c):

```
static PyObject *
posix_system(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    char *command;
    long sts;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s:system", &command))
        return NULL;
    Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
    sts = system(command);
    Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
    return PyInt_FromLong(sts);
}
```

Comment: While enlightening, this is an implementation detail -- unless the documentation specifies exactly which exceptions it does or does not raise, there's no reason why other implementations couldn't choose to raise exceptions under certain conditions.

Comment: Which is why one should be familiar with the runtime one uses. I assumed CPython since no more specific runtime environment was mentioned (Jython, PyPi). The [`os.system`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=os.system#os.system) docs for 2.7.1 don't mention exceptions which should/could be raised.

Answer (score 4):

`os.system` throws a `TypeError` if there is not exactly one string argument. If the `fork` fails due to resource or ulimit restrictions, it will return `-1`. If the argument is not valid in some way (like non-existing command), it will return a high error code. Apart from the aforementioned `TypeError`, `os.system` does not throw any exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking whether it throws an exception when the process you're calling ends with an error, the answer is no, you can call a program with `os.system()`, have it error out, and you will never know.

That's why you should use the `subprocess` module.